# Disable reboot/shutdown/suspend/etc from GUI

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown

I do heavy computations. I have set up a remote access to my PC. The real problem is that my family members use this PC as well, and they tend to forget that they shouldn't shut it down. I've tried moving /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/reboot, adding policies to polkit, using systemd-inhibit - this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Are there any dirty methods, like removing system files, which I can use to break the shutdown process? I could write a python script which removes those files and readds them when needed

OpenSuse, KDE

Comment: The proper way to do this is via `polkit` rules. Keep in mind [the new `polkit` uses `js` syntax for the rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/policykit.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PolicyKit's](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_113/opensuse-security/cha.security.policykit.html) local authority kit will allow you to control such actions. I believe you'd need to:

- create a file in the correct `polkit` directory/file that specifies the restrictions you'd like to place on the service,
- specify a group that these restrictions apply to,
- create the group,
- add users to the group.
- test.

Comment: I've added a rule which is restricted to this action ids:
`org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop
org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.restart
org.freedesktop.login1.reboot
org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions
org.freedesktop.login1.power-off
org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions
`

Comment: It disables reboot/shutdown/... etc while the user is logged in. However, I still have those options in my login window

Comment: Whoops... it is also restricted to the user group

Comment: Nevermind. Now it does `return polkit.Result.NO;` for anything that matches those conditions, without any restrictions to groups. Still I can shutdown from login window

Comment: In your file, you'd do something like this: `Identity=unix-group:no_shutdown` . Where `no shutdown` is the name of the group you'll create, and then add the restricted users to.

Comment: I have solved the problem for those users who have logged in, but I still have a shutdown option in login window. Can polkit manage this too?

Comment: That's a good question, and I am not sure as to the answer.

Comment: ... I believe you can: `org.freedesktop.login1.reboot` `org.freedesktop.login1.shutdown`, etc. I don't have a box to test on, but that should work.

Comment: That's exactly what my first comment was about XD
Thanks a lot for help, though

Comment: So to clarify, are you able to disable the actions you want to from the log in screen?

Comment: Technically I should be able to, but now I think that I don't need it